# The ultimate Java version table (J2EE, Java EE, Servlet, JSP, JSTL)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, jstl

I'm looking for a component break down of Java EE (or previously know as J2EE) and Java SE

E.g.

> **J2EE 1.3:** Servlet 2.3, JSP 1.2. JSTL 1.0, ...
>
> **J2EE 1.4:** Servlet 2.4, JSP 2.0, JSTL 1.1, ...
>
> **Java EE 1.5:** Servlet 2.5, JSP 2.1, JSTL 1.2, ...

In a simple table

It can be extracted from:
http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.3/docs/ , http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/ and http://java.sun.com/javaee/technologies/javaee5.jsp but I'm looking for a simple table.

Is there something like this out there? Or should I write one myself?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Wikipedia has a [Java EE version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history). Not in a table, but you can easily bake one yourself based on that if you want. To make it available to everyone, you could just add it as a table to the very same Wikipedia page. The current Java EE 6 uses by the way [Servlet 3.0](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html) / [JSP 2.2](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html) / [JSTL 1.2](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr052/index2.html).

JSP 2.2 is by the way nothing more than a "maintenance release" of JSP 2.1.

Comment: It seems the link no longer works... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Articles_for_deletion/Java_EE_version_history

Answer (score 41):

Here is one:
[image]

Also I want to add some information about Java EE7:

> In Java EE 7, no changes were made to JSP and JSTL because these specifications have not been updated.
>
> Expression Language has been removed from JSP and now has its own JSR (341).
>
> Servlets and JSF have both been updated.
>
> WebSocket 1.0 was introduced in Java EE 7.

And also please see this image for Java EE7:

[image]

Let me add this as well:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone was still looking for a tabular format ... I had a crack at a [java web specs. table](http://dev-answers.blogspot.com/2006/12/according-to-tld-or-attribute.html#specs) as a side-note to a blog post about EL errors. I haven't updated it to include Servlet 3.0 specs.

Answer (score 3):

This one is also nice:

```
+=============+================+====================+=============================================================================+
|   VERSION   |      DATE      |   JAVA EE / JDK    |                             FEATURES / CHANGES                              |
+=============+================+====================+=============================================================================+
| Servlet 4.0 | September 2017 | JavaEE 8           | HTTP/2                                                                      |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Servlet 3.1 | May 2013       | JavaEE 7           | Non-blocking I/O, HTTP protocol upgrade mechanism                           |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Servlet 3.0 | December 2009  | JavaEE 6, JavaSE 6 | Pluggability, Ease of development, Async Servlet, Security, File Uploading  |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Servlet 2.5 | September 2005 | JavaEE 5, JavaSE 5 | Requires JavaSE 5, supports annotation                                      |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Servlet 2.4 | November 2003  | J2EE 1.4, J2SE 1.3 | web.xml uses XML Schema                                                     |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Servlet 2.3 | August 2001    | J2EE 1.3, J2SE 1.2 | Addition of Filter                                                          |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Servlet 2.2 | August 1999    | J2EE 1.2, J2SE 1.2 | Becomes part of J2EE, introduced independent web applications in .war files |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Servlet 2.1 | November 1998  | Unspecified        | First official specification, added RequestDispatcher, ServletContext       |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Servlet 2.0 |                | JDK 1.1            | Part of Java Servlet Development Kit 2.0                                    |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Servlet 1.0 | June 1997      |                    |                                                                             |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33346887/8682071