# Difference between http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core and http://java.sun.com/jstl/core

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> //line-1
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c1" %>  //line-2
```

Is there any difference between line-1 and line-2. line-2 in jsp file is not giving any error but line-1 in another jsp giving error

> Can not find the tag library descriptor for
>   "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

I've seen the solution of the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593603/jstl-xmlns-namespace-differences-between-jsf-1-2-and-jsf-2-x) but could not get understand 
what is "Facelets"

> It is true that Facelets 1.x and 2.x uses different namespaces for the
>   JSTL tag library. It was less or more a namespace bug in Facelets 1.x
>   and has been fixed for Facelets 2.x.
>
> - The real JSTL 1.0 taglib uses the URI http://java.sun.com/jstl/core.
> - The real JSTL 1.1/1.2 taglib uses the URI http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core.
> - Facelets 1.x uses the URI http://java.sun.com/jstl/core.
> - Facelets 2.x uses the URI http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core.
> - Facelets 2.2+ uses the URI http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core.
>
> You can find all Facelets 2.x tags in the Facelets tag library
>   documentation. Facelets don't ship with the full tag set as the real
>   JSTL taglib. Only a few of the `<c:xxx>` and the full set of `<fn:xxx>`
>   are copied into Facelets. The `<fmt:xxx>`, `<sql:xxx>` and `<xml:xxx>` tags
>   are not taken over in Facelets.

Comment: you cannot have same prefix for multiple TLD's

Comment: see the error Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" I am using both jstl in separate jsp file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987908/how-to-resolve-can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-http-java-sun-co use this link. may be there something wrong included lib

Comment: I have included the library that's why not getting error in line-2. but what is the means of ../jsp/jstl.. and .../jstl/..(not having jsp).

Comment: you can find this question answer on [this][1] SO question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593603/jstl-xmlns-namespace-differences-between-jsf-1-2-and-jsf-2-x

Comment: So, your question is essentially: "What is Facelets?" and the remainder is actually irrelevant? Have you tried copypasting "What is Facelets?" into Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using (uses `JSTL 1.2`)

`<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

means to use EL Expressions you do not need `<c:out>`. You can directly insert EL expressions onto jsp page like `${propertyName}`

While using (uses `JSTL 1.0` deprecated)

`<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/core" %>`

You can not use EL Expressions directly on jsp page you need `<c:out>`. EL expressions on the page will not work. e.g. `<c:out value=”${propertyName}”>`.

Also your web-app version (found in `web.xml`) should be down to 2.3 to use `http://java.sun.com/jsp/core` which is again too old.

Conclusion:

`<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` - Can use EL directly

`<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/core" %>` - Can not use EL directly