# How Servlet 3.1 differs to Servlet 3.0

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

Is servlet 3.1 under JavaEE 7?

Which version of eclipse supports servlet 3.1 development?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is servlet 3.1 under JavaEE 7?

Servlet 3.1 is introduced with JavaEE 7.

> How Servlet 3.1 differs to Servlet 3.0?

Regarding the new changes in Servlet 3.1, read this blog post by Arun Gupta: [What's new in Servlet 3.1 ? - Java EE 7 moving forward](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/what_s_new_in_servlet)

> And I also want to know which version of eclipse support servlet 3.1 development.

The new version of Eclipse 4.3 (named Kepler) supports Java EE 7 technologies. See Arun Gupta's blog post: [Java EE 7 support in Eclipse 4.3](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/java_ee_7_support_in1)

Comment: Arun Gupta's blog post seems OK currently (July 2017).

Comment: The link is broken now

Answer (score 24):

> Servlet 3.1 vs Servlet 3.0 along with others too

```
+=============+================+====================+=============================================================================+
|   VERSION   |      DATE      |   JAVA EE / JDK    |                             FEATURES / CHANGES                              |
+=============+================+====================+=============================================================================+
| Servlet 3.1 | May 2013       | JavaEE 7           | Non-blocking I/O, HTTP protocol upgrade mechanism                           |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Servlet 3.0 | December 2009  | JavaEE 6, JavaSE 6 | Pluggability, Ease of development, Async Servlet, Security, File Uploading  |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Servlet 2.5 | September 2005 | JavaEE 5, JavaSE 5 | Requires JavaSE 5, supports annotation                                      |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Servlet 2.4 | November 2003  | J2EE 1.4, J2SE 1.3 | web.xml uses XML Schema                                                     |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Servlet 2.3 | August 2001    | J2EE 1.3, J2SE 1.2 | Addition of Filter                                                          |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Servlet 2.2 | August 1999    | J2EE 1.2, J2SE 1.2 | Becomes part of J2EE, introduced independent web applications in .war files |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Servlet 2.1 | November 1998  | Unspecified        | First official specification, added RequestDispatcher, ServletContext       |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Servlet 2.0 |                | JDK 1.1            | Part of Java Servlet Development Kit 2.0                                    |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Servlet 1.0 | June 1997      |                    |                                                                             |
+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet#History)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer given by Eng.Fouad: Servlet 3.1 was indeed introduced with Java EE 7, but it's also implemented standalone by various servers that are themselves not Java EE products, e.g. [Tomcat 8](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) or [Jetty 9.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_%28web_server%29).

As for the changes, I collected [a number or articles on my ZEEF page](https://javaee7.zeef.com/arjan.tijms#block_229) that are specifically about the new things in Servlet 3.1.

As a short summary; non-blocking IO and some security features like the '*' role and the possibility to deny HTTP methods not explicitly covered by security constraints were some of the major changes.