# why javax.servlet-api doesn't contain jstl?

Tags: java, maven, servlets

I read example describes cretation simple web mvc application. At this examples in `pom.xml` added only

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

but when I invoke this application I got same error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JstlUtils.exposeLocalizationContext(JstlUtils.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.exposeHelpers(JstlView.java:135)

...
```

after adding

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

problem is absence.

Is it normally that javax.servlet doesn't contain jstl or is it my error?

Or is it author's example error or maybe something another?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use jstl when working with the servlet API. You can also write directly to the outputStream. For that reason it makes sense that these are separate artifacts.

Comment: Are there exist link between versions of  jstl and servlet-api ?

Comment: See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013879/the-ultimate-java-version-table-j2ee-java-ee-servlet-jsp-jstl

Comment: I don't see information about servlet 3 (only 2.5) there

Comment: Please read and follow the links on that page... or google for java ee versions

Comment: You really need to work on your search skills: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history#Java_EE_6_.28December_10.2C_2009.29

Comment: I saw this link bit I don't understand how I can to know answer using this page

Comment: Back to original question: you need to specify both, Spring can't specify for you which JSTL version you want to use, neither  for the servlet specs. It means: if you expect your webapplication to run in a JEE6 webcontainer, your application can use Java Servlet (API) 3.0 and JSTL 1.2.

Comment: @ Robert Scholte but if I use only servlet container Tomcat

Comment: Look up the version of Tomcat, and see which JEE version it supports. http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: strange that I can work wih tomcat 7 and servlet api 3.1