# Issue regarding JSP Forward

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

In my code I am trying to forward my request by using below line

```
<jsp:forward page = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Welcome.do"/>
```

However its giving error below

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /obajsp/OBAHeader.jsp(3,27) JBWEB004214: Error unquoting attribute value
```

Please someone help me to understand what is issue in my written code?

EDIT:
**this was currently working in production without any issue and giving issue in my local IDE**

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the expression language, rather than a scriptlet?

```
<jsp:forward page = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Welcome.do"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan for answer. But i need reason because this was  currently working in production without any issue and giving issue in my local IDE.

Comment: Did you change the underlying [jsp version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013879/the-ultimate-java-version-table-j2ee-java-ee-servlet-jsp-jstl), maybe indirectly by upgrading to a newer server verison?

Answer (score 0):

```
<jsp:forward page = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Welcome.do"/>
```

you dont need inline java to get the context path. expressionlanguage is much more comfortable.

Comment: Thanks Philipp for answer. But i need reason because this was currently working in production without any issue and giving issue in my local IDE

Comment: @user416120 maybe a caching problem? you should add that information to your question!

Comment: maybe there are different libaries in use