# Which [JSF, JSP, EL, Facelets] version is compatible with Servlet Container x.y & JEE 1.z?

Tags: jsp, jsf, servlets, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I am a little confused which version of `JSF, JSP, EL, Facelets` is compatible with which `Servlet Container APIs & JEE 1.z` version.

For example, `JSF 2.0` comes with a dependency on `EL 2.1 + Servlet 2.5`.

`Facelets`(I dont know the `version no`) was part of `JEE 6` version.

Can someone provide all these details in a table format as below?

[image]

Comment: For the JSF compatibility part, is "Minimum requirements" section here helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info For the remainder, your concrete question really duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/q/2013879

Comment: @BalusC: Oh yes, its already there. My search results failed to get notice of that. You may close it as a duplicate.

Comment: Okay :) Additional note: https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/JEE