# Spring boot: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletMapping;

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, nosuchmethoderror

When I run this application on built-in server or other tomcat server it
 gives me following error message. I am using jdk8, STS V-3.9.7. Can someone help me resolve it

Simple Springboot application with following content:

application.properties file for view mapping

```
    spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jspViews/
    spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

> index.jsp

```
    <body>
       <h3>Application is working</h3>
     </body>
```

> Controller class

```
    @Controller
    public class AppController {    
       @RequestMapping("/")
       public String indexPage() {
           return "index";
       }
    }
```

> pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ehospitalsso</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

web.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" version="4.0">

      <display-name>demo</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>   
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>    
      </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

> Error StackTrace ::

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHttpServletMapping()Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletMapping;
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setRequest(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:690) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.<init>(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:114) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.wrapRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:917) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:358) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.13-dev]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.13-dev]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.13-dev]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.13-dev]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.13-dev]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.13-dev]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.13-dev]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

> Screen Sort:

[image]

> Kind attend Mr.Avijit for update pox.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>        
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>Demo_App</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Demo_App</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>      

        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

> ServletInitializer  Class

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoAppApplication.class);
    }

}
```

> DemoAppApplication class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of your project structure ?

Comment: Hi Avijit, I have update it with screenshot. Please help?

Comment: Can you please check my answer ?

Comment: Ramesh remove `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>` this dependency and add all dependency in my answer

Comment: Try deleting the line `<relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->` in your pom.xml.

Comment: Dear Avijit, It is giving same error.

Comment: @ Avijit Barua: Dear sir, post updated with updated pom.xml

Comment: Please post your main class and servlet initializer

Comment: Could you please now...

Comment: You haven't posted your `DemoAppApplication.class` and `servlet initializer class`

Comment: DemoAppApplication.class and servlet initializer class posted

Comment: @RameshKumar Check my answer step by step. And let us know

Comment: @RameshKumar Have you checked ?

Answer (score 22):

I think there is a version mismatch (possibly a Bug?) in Spring Boot.

Spring Boot 2.1.X uses Tomcat 9 which has the Servlet API v4.
But Spring Boot Web 2.1.X still incorporates Servlet API v3.1.

You should solve the problem by downgrading the spring-boot-starter-tomcat to version 2.0.X.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Edit:
It might as well work just to change the Tomcat version property.

```
    <properties>
        <tomcat.version>8.5.37</tomcat.version>
    <properties>
```

Comment: Your first suggestion worked for me (downgraded from Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE). Thanks! .. For the second option, where would those lines go?

Comment: The `tomcat.version` property is a normal Maven property in your pom.xml. Just add the `tomcat.version` to your existing Maven properties.

Comment: Thanks! This resolved my problem. I think the property setting is a nicer way of mending.

Comment: Please remember that second solution (although IMHO is more elegant) will only work if your parent pom is `spring-boot-starter-parent`. Use the first solution if you are using different parent pom and Spring Boot is added manually to your dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and the cause was the jsp-api didn't fit to the corresponding servlet-api version.
As Sven Döring already mentioned Spring Boot 2.1.x uses Tomcat 9 which uses/provides Servlet API v4. For this you need jsp-api 2.3.3 otherwise you can get the NoSuchMethodError.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

More info about the version matching can be found here: [The ultimate Java version table (J2EE, Java EE, Servlet, JSP, JSTL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013879/the-ultimate-java-version-table-j2ee-java-ee-servlet-jsp-jstl/26074899#26074899)
Unfortunately Tomcat 9 and Servlet-API 4 is missing in this list.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to add to answer of Sven Döring solution for gradle:

```
compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: springVer) {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: springTomcatVer)
```

At this point, I set the params:

> springVer='2.1.8.RELEASE'
>   springTomcatVer='2.0.9.RELEASE'

Answer (score 1):

merge your DemoAppApplication with servlet initializer as follow:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoAppApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoAppApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(DemoAppApplication.class);
}
```

}

or add `@Configuration` annotation to class that extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`

Answer (score 1):

Below Fix Worked for me. Thanks Sven Döring

```
<properties>
        <tomcat.version>8.5.37</tomcat.version>
    <properties>
```

Comment: Please consider deleting your answer and then upvoting the answer your referenced: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Answer (score 0):

because servlet-api version not match tomcat version.
if you use tomcat 9.x should check your servlet-api version over the v4
also when you use tomcat 8.x should use servlet-api v3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30589865)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still stuck after the above suggestions:

My issue was due to including `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0` in my `build.gradle` file dependencies (although the same issue could occur with maven).

If you're using embedded Tomcat, the `javax` library is included in the `tomcat-embed-core` jar which is found in the maven library `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`.  Remove the reference to `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0`.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the issue by adding the servlet_api.jar to project lib path from apache-tomcat-9.0.27\lib\servlet_api.jar.