# Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in Spring MVC

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

I had some problems when I first wrote the Spring MVC project
[image]
My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>springmvc01-base</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>springmvc01-base Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- SpringMVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 日志 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring5和Thymeleaf整合包 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>springmvc01-base</finalName>
  </build>

</project>
```

I've added servlets in my dependencies and built successfully with Maven
[image]

However, servlet-api does not appear in the target/project/WEB-INF/lib directory
[image]

Can you help me?

I tried clear and package maven and it didn't work

Comment: With scope=provided, it's normal that the servlet jar doesn't appear in your WEB-INF/lib. It's expected to be part of your server environment - Tomcat - rather than your app.

Comment: I'd normally say this looks like a case of mismatched dependency and Tomcat versions (see, for instance, https://stackoverflow.com/q/54122724/796761). But It looks like Tomcat 9 is what you're running, which does support Servlet 4 that you've specified, which does have the method specified.

Answer (score -2):

Please try changing

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

to

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

see [Maven Dependency Scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope)

If you want to deploy with a Servlet container, and the container already provides an appropriate version of the Servlet API, you can use `<scope>provided</scope>`; if you don't want to rely on an external Servlet container, you'd better delete `<scope> provided</scope>`.

This is my understanding, I hope it can help you.

Comment: Didn't solve my problem, but thank you very much for your help 

Comment: This is not correct, the reason provided must be specified is that Tomcat already **provided** this library for you.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.
I want servlet-api.jar to appear in the packaged directory to ignore this question, I feel guilty for my wrong answer.@MarkRotteveel